# getting undefined result on browser console

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function perm(){
var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",l=x.length;for(i=0;i<l;i+=2) {if(i+1<l)o+=" +
"x.charAt(i+1);try{o+=x.charAt(i);}catch(e){}}return o;}f(\"ufcnitnof x({)av" +
" r,i=o\\\"\\\"o,=l.xelgnhtl,o=;lhwli(e.xhcraoCedtAl(1/)3=!84{)rt{y+xx=l;=+;" +
"lc}tahce({)}}of(r=i-l;1>i0=i;--{)+ox=c.ahAr(t)i};erutnro s.buts(r,0lo;)f}\\" +
"\"(0),4\\\"\\\\01\\\\0t\\\\\\\\\\\\03\\\\06\\\\03\\\\\\\\24\\\\03\\\\01\\\\" +
"\\\\4U03\\\\\\\\16\\\\0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_\\\\0L00\\\\\\\\EY^MG[UWAWOJRD^ozrs" +
"u:'4K)I~vye.{P/ef&jospcmqsq14\\\\00\\\\03\\\\\\\\25\\\\06\\\\02\\\\\\\\37\\" +
"\\03\\\\01\\\\\\\\10\\\\07\\\\32\\\\05\\\\02\\\\\\\\37\\\\06\\\\00\\\\\\\\4" +
"W00\\\\\\\\35\\\\03\\\\01\\\\\\\\14\\\\02\\\\00\\\\\\\\14\\\\0}\\\\01\\\\0f" +
"\\\\2?;'.qiq)a&)V5LO27\\\\0C\\\\V[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\NZMD\\\"\\\\f(;} ornture;" +
"}))++(y)^(iAtdeCoarchx.e(odrChamCro.fngriSt+=;o27=1y%+;y+0)<4(iif){++;i<l;i" +
"=0(ior;fthnglex.l=\\\\,\\\\\\\"=\\\",o iar{vy)x,f(n ioctun\\\"f)\")"         ;
while(x=eval(x));
}
temp = perm();
console.log(temp);
</script>
```

Getting undefined message on console instead of function result. How can I get the function result on console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = eval(x);
return x;
```

and remove the `while(x=eval(x));`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yk7Nw/)

Comment: Thanks, it works.Site says "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes".. Give me 6 minutes to accept as answer.